# Unhandled Runtime Error when using github app authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, github, next.js, github-api

I'm trying to use github App auth, following the steps here - https://github.com/octokit/auth-app.js/

For testing it out, I created this simple script.

```
const githubLogin = async () => {
  const auth = createAppAuth({
    appId: ...,
    privateKey: "...",
    clientId: "...",
    clientSecret: "...",
  });
  
  const appAuthentication =  auth({ type: "app" })
  console.log(appAuthentication);
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const hello = api.example.hello.useQuery({ text: "from tRPC" });

  return (
      <main>
      <div>
        <button onClick={githubLogin}>Login with Github</button>
      </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};
```

On clicking on "Login with Github", I get an "unhandled runtime exception".
I also tried to resolve the promise without using await `auth({ type: "app" }).then((res) => {console.log(res)};` but it's throwing the same error.
I mostly do Python and need to test something out using this so I might be missing something obvious, but I don't find better examples in the docs.

For `privateKey:` I'm using this section(from an example image below) copied from the GitHub-generated key and not the `.pem` file downloaded as this one works well for requests in python requests module
[image]

Full error from the console:

```
Promise.then (async)        
githubLogin @   index.tsx:21
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue    @   react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins    @   react-dom.development.js:9097
eval    @   react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1    @   react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @   react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:6430
```

Comment: Please post the full error message and traceback.